Fluent-bit Match not working except for *
I'm using AWS Fargate and log_router containers with a custom Fluent Bit configuration to route logs. Here is my current configuration:
[FILTER]
    Name    grep
    Match   cw
    Exclude log unwatedtext

[FILTER]
    Name    modify
    Match   cw
    Remove  source
    Remove  container_id
    Remove  container_name
    Remove  ec2_instance_id
    Remove  ecs_cluster
    Remove  ecs_task_arn
    Remove  ecs_task_definition

[OUTPUT]
    Name                cloudwatch_logs
    Match               cw
    log_key             log
    region              eu-west-1
    log_group_name      /ecs/container
    log_stream_prefix   fluent-bit-
    auto_create_group   On
    log_format          json/emf

[OUTPUT]
    Name                s3 
    bucket              mybucket
    total_file_size     100M
    log_key             log
    match               *
    s3_key_format       /$TAG/%Y/%m/%d/
    use_put_object      on
    upload_timeout      1M
    region              eu-west-1

Currently, the unwatedtext is being removed for both CloudWatch and S3 outputs. However, I want to remove it only for CloudWatch and send all logs, including those with unwatedtext, to S3.
How can I modify my Fluent Bit configuration to achieve this?
Additional Information:

Fluent Bit version: AWS_FOR_FLUENT_BIT_VERSION  2.32.2.20240627
AWS Fargate setup
Using log_router containers

Update - 22-Jul-24
I have found the issue. Any help will be appreciated
Match is only working for * and I dont see why this is happening.
Here are my updated config.
lua script
function process_record(tag, timestamp, record)
    print("Input tag: ", tag)
    print("Record: ", record["tag"])
    local s3_log = {}
    local cw_log = {}

    for k, v in pairs(record) do
        cw_log[k] = v
        cw_log["tag"] = "cw"

        s3_log[k] = v
        s3_log["tag"] = "s3"
    end
    print("S3 tag: ", s3_log["tag"])
    print("CW tag: ", cw_log["tag"])
    print("S3 Log: ", s3_log["log"])
    print("CW Log: ", cw_log["log"])
    return 2, timestamp, {s3_log, cw_log}
end

config
[SERVICE]
    flush 1
    daemon off
    log_level debug

[FILTER]
    Name          lua
    Match         *
    script        /append_tag.lua
    call          process_record

[FILTER]
    Name          lua
    Match         $tag cw
    script        /print.lua
    call          process_record


[FILTER]
    Name          rewrite_tag
    Match         cw
    Rule          $tag .* cw true
    Emitter_Name  cw_emitted
[OUTPUT]
    Name                cloudwatch_logs
    Match               *cw*
#    Match               *
#    Match_regex         ^(cw)$
    log_key             log
    region              af-south-1
    log_group_name      /ecs/log
    log_stream_prefix   fluent-bit-
    auto_create_group   On
    log_format          json/emf


Note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead.

posted https://serverfault.com/questions/1162871/fluent-bit-match-not-working-except-for

After working on this I have finally found the solution.
Here is my working config that is pushing data to cw and s3 and removing some logs for cw
logDestinations.conf
[FILTER]
    Name          lua
    Match         *
    script        /script.lua
    call          process_record

[FILTER]
    Name          rewrite_tag
    Match_regex   .*demo.*
    Rule          $tag "^(cw)$" cw.$container_id true
    Emitter_Name  re_emitted_cw

[FILTER]
    Name    grep
    Match_regex   .*cw.*
    Exclude tag s3

[FILTER]
    Name    grep
    Match_regex   .*cw.*
    Exclude log /.*message\":\"remove.*/

[FILTER]
    Name    grep
    Match_regex   .*demo.*
    Exclude tag cw

[OUTPUT]
    Name                cloudwatch_logs
    Match_regex         .*cw.*
    log_key             log
    region              af-south-1
    log_group_name      /ecs/demo
    log_stream_prefix   fluent-bit-
    auto_create_group   On
    log_format          json/emf


[OUTPUT]                   
    bucket     s3_bucket
    total_file_size    200M
    log_key    log
    Match_regex   .*demo.*
    s3_key_format    /demo/%Y-%m-%d/$TAG/
    use_put_object    on
    upload_timeout    1M
    region    af-south-1
    Name    s3

script.lua
function process_record(tag, timestamp, record)
    
    local s3_log = {}
    local cw_log = {}

    if record["log"] == nil then
        record["log"] = record["message"] or "default_log_message"
    end

    for k, v in pairs(record) do
        cw_log[k] = v
        cw_log["tag"] = "cw"

        s3_log[k] = v
        s3_log["tag"] = "s3"
    end
    
    return 2, timestamp, {s3_log, cw_log}
end

Dockerfile
FROM cr.fluentbit.io/fluent/fluent-bit
ADD logDestinations.conf /logDestinations.conf
ADD script.lua /script.lua


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
